# Adding a number with a plus button

Tags: jquery

I want to make a button that will ad a number to existing field. My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="str">
    <div class="str-img"><div>10</div></div>
    <div class="stat-plus"><img src="images/plus.png" alt="Plus"></div>
    <div class="stat-minus"><img src="images/minus.png" alt="Minus"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="register-str" value="10">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.str .stat-plus img').click(function() {
        var val = $('.str-img div').val();
        var new_val = parseInt($('.str-img div').val(),10) + 1 ;
        $('.str-img div').val(new_val);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text()` to the get the div's text instead of `.val()` which is use to get the `value` of an element. Try this. I've completed the function with both increment and decrement capabilities.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.stat-plus, .stat-minus', '.str').click(function() {
        var $display = $('.str-img div');
        var new_val = parseInt($display.text()) + ($(this).is('.stat-plus') ? 1 : -1);
        $display.text(new_val);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="str">
    <div class="str-img"><div>10</div></div>
    <div class="stat-plus"><img src="images/plus.png" alt="Plus"></div>
    <div class="stat-minus"><img src="images/minus.png" alt="Minus"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="register-str" value="10">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `val` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

Instead of `val` method, you can use `text` or `html` method on `$('.str-img div')` element, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('.str .stat-plus img').click(function() {
            var val = $('.str-img div').html();
            var new_val = parseInt(val,10) + 1 ;
            $('.str-img div').html(new_val);
        });
    }
);
```

```html
<div class="str">
  <div class="str-img">
    <div>10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stat-plus"><img src="images/plus.png" alt="Plus"></div>
  <div class="stat-minus"><img src="images/minus.png" alt="Minus"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="register-str" value="10">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```